# Stop loop function on a button's click

Tags: jquery, html

I've a series of arrays  which I'm displaying one after another using jquery loop.

Check [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramansharma89/fcLso5c9/3/).

Now I want to stop it when a user click on "stop it now" button.

HTML:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsumd dolor sit amet.</h1>
<div id="div1">Answer One</div>
<div class="stop">
    <button>Stop it Now.</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{text-align:center;}
h1{padding:30px; margin:0 0 0 30px;}
#div1{padding:20px;margin-top:0; text-align:center;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var items = ["Answer Two", "Answer Three", "Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six", "Answer One"],
    $text = $( '#div1' ),
    delay = .2; //seconds

function loop ( delay ) {
    $.each( items, function ( i, elm ){
        $text.delay( delay*1E3).hide();
        $text.queue(function(){
            $text.html( items[i] );
            $text.dequeue();
        });
        $text.show();
        $text.queue(function(){
            if ( i == items.length -1 ) {
                loop(delay);   
            }
            $text.dequeue();
        });
    });
}

loop( delay );
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a function with some activity and wrap it into `window.setInterval()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use [`.stop(true, false)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). Doing this will clear the queue and without executing the pending functions.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $text.stop(true, false);
})
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcLso5c9/4/)

Comment: and what if I want to restart it on click of an another button?

Comment: @RamanSharma You should be able to call `loop(delay);` to start it again

Comment: I'm not much code savvy person. a Fiddle will be much appreciated if you can. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag. Try this:

```
var flag = false;

$(".stop button").click(function(){
    flag=true;
});
function loop ( delay ) {
    $.each( items, function ( i, elm ){
        $text.delay( delay*1E3).hide();
        $text.queue(function(){
            $text.html( items[i] );
            $text.dequeue();
        });
        $text.show();
        $text.queue(function(){
            if ( i == items.length -1 ) {
                loop(delay);   
            }
            $text.dequeue();
        });
        if(flag) break;
    });
}
```

Comment: This always ends on `Answer one` as each function call always iterates through the entire array before being called again.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the logic you use to implement a timer it makes the code much simpler and also means you can simply call `clearInterval` on the timer to stop the text changing. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = ["Answer Two", "Answer Three", "Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six", "Answer One"],
        $text = $('#div1'),
        delay = 200, // miliseconds
        itemIndex = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $text.text(items[itemIndex % items.length]);
        itemIndex++;
    }, delay);

    $('button').click(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    })
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcLso5c9/8/)

Comment: Thanks for this simplified alternative Rory McCrossan. It's perfect. :)

Comment: what if I want to restart it?

Comment: You just need to call `setInterval()` again.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. sorry not much knowledge of jquery.

here is [updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/ramansharma89/3uh0meo4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I added a parameter called "stopLoop" which is being initialized as false.
Once button is clicked that parameter becomes true and stops the loop.
Here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcLso5c9/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var stopLoop = false;
```

$("button").click(function(){stopLoop = true;});
    var items = ["Answer Two", "Answer Three", "Answer Four", "Answer Five", "Answer Six", "Answer One"],
        $text = $( '#div1' ),
        delay = .2; //seconds

```
function loop ( delay ) {
    if (stopLoop) return;
    $.each( items, function ( i, elm ){
        $text.delay( delay*1E3).hide();
        $text.queue(function(){
            $text.html( items[i] );
            $text.dequeue();
        });
        $text.show();
        $text.queue(function(){
            if ( i == items.length -1 ) {
                loop(delay);   
            }
            $text.dequeue();
        });
    });
}

loop( delay );
```

});

You can use almost the same code to have a start/stop functionality