# Change class name with variables in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to change the name of a class every 2 seconds, based on a list of names (var "items").

I found a pretty good SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065165/stop-loop-function-on-a-buttons-click) and tried to change it to my needs. It now works for me, but I don't know, how to remove $text and the div "#div1" - because I don't need it. In the other SO it was used to change the html text of the div. But I don't need this, I only want to change the class name of the section - I tried to remove this code, but then it do not work anymore.

HTML:

```
<section class="steps">class name of this section changes (see inspector)</section>
<div id="div1"></div> <!-- this could be removed -->
<button>Stop it Now.</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var items = ["one", "two", "three"],
        $text = $( '#div1' ),
        $step = $( 'section.steps' ),
        delay = 2; //seconds

    function loop ( delay ) {
        $.each( items, function ( i, elm ){
            $text.delay( delay*1E3).hide();
            $text.queue(function(){
                $text.html( items[i] );
                $text.dequeue(); // this is not needed
                $step.addClass( items[i] ).delay(2000).queue(function(){
                  $(this).removeClass( items[i] ).dequeue();
                });
            });
            $text.show();
            $text.queue(function(){
                if ( i == items.length -1 ) {
                    loop(delay);   
                }
                $text.dequeue();
            });
        });
    }

    loop( delay );

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $text.stop(true, false);
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4onx6epc/1/)

Comment: after the stop function called, put this: `$text.remove();`

Comment: my final fiddle, thanks to bgaynor78: http://jsfiddle.net/ary8k30z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I simplified how you're adding/removing classes:

```
function loop ( delay ) {
        $.each( items, function ( i, elm ){
            $text.delay( delay*1E3);
            $text.queue(function(){
                $text.html( items[i] );
                $text.dequeue(); // this is not needed
                // Sanitize the classlist
                $text.attr('class', 'step');
                // Added these two lines instead of the queue/dequeue
                $text.addClass( items[i]);
            });

            $text.queue(function(){
                if ( i == items.length -1 ) {
                    loop(delay);   
                }
                $text.dequeue();
            });
        });
    }
```

Basically, we'll take the current index and add the class like you had, but in order to remove the class that was there before, I'm just going back to the previous index value. I also changed the value of the `$text` var to be pointing to your `step` div.

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/t30cf9qr/35/)

Comment: You don't actually need the `.hide()` or `.show()` on the `$text` element either. I've updated the fiddle and my answer to reflect this

Comment: I have no idea why, but this is not working with jquery 2.1.3, which I am using. :S With this jquery version, the last added class (three in this cases) will not be removed.

Comment: I see, not sure what changed from v1.7.1 to 2.1.3 in jquery about how it's handling this, but the simpliest solution I could come up with was to santize the classlist before each addClass() call. I've updated the answer and the fiddle to show. Basically, just change the class attribute to the base class with `$text.attr('class', 'step');` before the add class in the `loop` function.